# AD groups are not showing in people picker after migration of SharePoint 2010 site to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration

We have migrated my SharePoint 2010 application to SharePoint 2013. We are using two Active Directory with same users and security groups. We have done trust relationship between both the ADs.

After migration we are able to see all the users of both the domains and groups of current domain in which my SharePoint 2013 server is installed but we are not getting security groups of second AD in people picker.

Some of the AD groups of second domain are already present in permission as it was added in SharePoint 2010 before migration but users of these group are not able to access SharePoint 2013 site (Showing Access Denied Error).

Please suggest me solution if anybody had seen this issue before.

Answer (score 2):

Try to configure PeoplePicker as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602075.aspx#section4). The article tells you that this should only be necessary with a one-way trust, but i have seen lots of situations where it had to be configured also with a two-way trust.

You do not need an account in the other domain, as you already have a two-way trust. So your STSADM-command can be slightly modified:

```
STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:yourdomain.local;domain:yourtrusteddomain.local" -url http://sharepoint
```